# How to check if field of type reference revisions is paragraph or others?

Tags: entities, paragraphs

I am creating paragraph field programmatically dynamically from array.

The logic for creating a paragraph field is different from others entity revisions.

Is there a way we can identify if field of entity type revisions is paragraph and not others?

Comment: Given the less information in your question, I marked it as a possible duplicate. If you feel, that the other question's answer doesn't meet what you've been looking for, please provide more details about where you need to know the field's target type, what you like to achieve, and/or add code snippets of what you have already.

Comment: I agree, starting from a code snippet there is probably a shortcut, you can get the field definition directly from the field object.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz your solution is exactly what i was looking for!